# Complex Block Diagram Reduction

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, block-diagram

I have this Block Diagram and I need to simply it. But I'm still confused and this is my progress currently. I don't know is this correct or not. Maybe someone can help me.

[image: Block Diagram]
[image: Part 1]
[image: Part 2]

Comment: Although it can somewhat be inferred from your post, please consider writing an actual question.

Comment: Actually that's a real question. I just need to simplfy it.

Comment: Real questions have question marks. "I would like to simplify this diagram." Is not a question. "How can I simplify this diagram?" is a question. More to the point, you should explain how or where you are stuck, rather than just showing the attempt.

Comment: Ah okee, I'm sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you took what I would consider to be the best (similar) path: -

[image]

I'm sure you can double check your answer against mine if you took the final stages yourself. Oh, here's a couple more steps: -

[image]

Sorry about the error. The next stage is this: -

[image]

This will produce the same answer that you got.

Comment: I calculated your answer and i found the answer it's little bit different.
The answer is 

G1G2G3G4/ 1 - H1G3 - G2G3H2 - G1G2G3G4

Comment: @Kevin18 I see an error in one area of my answer and have corrected it (see red lines/words). If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: Well,thank you for your feedback. i really appreciate it.

Comment: We got there in the end @Kevin18